# CentOS 5/Linux UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems, fsck

Getting an error in a VM Boot that says

```
Checking filesystems
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 contains a file system with errors, check forced
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00:
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found

/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

How do I fix this issue? Hours of googling didn't explain anything.

Comment: Have you tried running `fsck` yet?

Comment: Yep, fsck -y /dev/sda/*

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: fsck -y /dev/sda* returns http://screensnapr.com/v/Tja4L9.png

Comment: Is that a no then?

Comment: http://screensnapr.com/v/dFIjQK.png

Comment: The above is what I ran and then the above is my error, I tried running it with the other command, no luck. http://screensnapr.com/v/dGoriM.png

Comment: If you are unable to read and understand the error message provided then you should speak to your manager about getting some basic education, you desperately need it.

Comment: What does `/dev/sda/*` have to do with `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00`? Also running `fsck` on multiple devices which arent necessarily filesystems is a really bad idea, especially if youre going to tack `-y` on to that command.

Answer (score 4):

Just like [the error message](https://serverfault.com/q/393173/7360) says, run `fsck` against `/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00`.